# matplotlib how to tidy things up please

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have got a graph of a falling object.

Here is my program.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = 98.  # height (m)
g = 9.8  # acceleration (m/s^2)
vt = 53. # terminal velocity (m/s)
m = (13 * 14 + 6) * 0.454  # mass (kg)

z = np.arange(0, 1.+5e-4, 1e-3) * h
t = vt / g * np.arccosh(np.exp(g * z / vt**2))
v = vt * np.sqrt(1 - np.exp(- 2 * g * z / vt**2))
# v = vt * np.tanh(g * t / vt)  # equivalent
a = g * np.cosh(g * t / vt) ** -2
ek = m * v**2 / 2

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(6., 8.)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
ax1.set_xlabel('time (t)')
ax1.set_ylabel('speed (m/s)')
ax1.plot(t,v)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(322)
ax2.set_xlabel('speed (m/s)')
ax2.set_ylabel('height (m)')
ax2.plot(v, h - z)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(323)
ax3.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax3.set_ylabel('height (m)')
ax3.plot(t, h - z)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(325)
ax3.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax3.set_ylabel('acceleration (m/s^2)')
ax3.set_ylim([0,10.])
ax3.plot(t, a)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(324)
ax4.set_xlabel('kinetic energy (kJ)')
ax4.set_ylabel('height (m)')
ax4.plot(ek/1e3, h - z)

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(326)
ax5.set_xlabel('acceleration (m/s^2)')
ax5.set_ylabel('height (m)')
ax5.set_xlim([0,10.])
ax5.plot(a, h - z)

plt.savefig('jum.png', dpi=300)
zfinal = -6. * 12 * 0.0254
```

Here is the graph.

[the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UeyJ.png)

As you can see, it is basically working but I want to tidy it up.

1. The axis labels are all on top of the adjacent plots.
2. There are too many vertical axis labels in the top left plot.
3. Don't know how to do proper superscripts with the "^2" in the axis labels.

Can anybody help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Ha looks like I screwed up the axis object names a bit (1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5). Not that it really matters  <nervous_laugh>

Answer (score 0):

To make something appear as an expression in matplotlib, wrap it in "$". As in:

```
ax3.set_ylabel('acceleration ($m/s^2$)')
...
ax5.set_xlabel('acceleration ($m/s^2$)')
```

Many of the issues disappear if you make the plot a little larger:

```
fig.set_size_inches(12., 16.)
```

To change the y-ticks of the top-left figure use:

```
ax1.set_yticks(range(0, 41, 8))
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: If this answers your question, do you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: On one level, yes it does answer my question, though if you don't mind, I would rather leave the question open to additional answers for the time being. Many thanks again for your time.

Comment: Just FYI, accepting an answer doesn't close the question. It remains open for additional answers / comments / edits.

Comment: Well, does it answer your question now?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you wanna look into is label formatting:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/text_intro.html
Especially size and position.

From my experience you will always encounter troubles when plotting complex graphs in matplotlib. If you are to plot lots of this kind of figure,you should take a look at other plotting libraries.
I use seaborn, you should already be familiar with it since it is a matplotlib fork.

Comment: Thank you, though I do not think that I will plot lots of this kind of figure.